# LDAP specific ACL for each users

Tags: linux, ldap, acl, openldap

I'm looking for a way to allow LDAP users to write into a branch that has their names. For example, I want each users A, B, C allowed to write into a cn=A,ou=foo, cn=B,ou=foo, cn=C,ou=foo...
Is there a way to do that without writing it explicitly.

Not like that:

```
access: to subtree="cn=A,ou=foo"
  by dn.exact="uid=A,ou=people" write
access: to subtree="cn=B,ou=foo"
  by dn.exact="uid=B,ou=people" write
...
```

With a regex maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that will work:

```
olcAccess: to dn.regex=".+,cn=([^,]+),ou=foo$"
  by dn.exact,expand="uid=$1,ou=people" write
  by users read
  by * none
```

Each user will have write access to a branch with their name in `ou=foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify this for every user. You just need

```
access: to * by self write
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't enough clear, but I don't want user A to be able to write in cn=B,ou=foo, in my example.

Comment: That is exactly what this does. Everybody can write to their own entry, and no permission is granted hereby to even read any other entry, let alone write to it.

Comment: But the thing is, it's not their entries. I know it works on the user's entry.

Comment: What's not their entries?

Comment: The entries 'cn=A,ou=foo, cn=B,ou=foo, cn=C,ou=foo...' are not user entries. The're just entries that match user names, somewhere in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

Directory Schema:

> ```
>    -dc=myorg,dc=com
>       -ou=nonprod
>         -ou=hostdefinitions
>       -ou=people
>          -cn=user1
>          -cn=user2
>       -ou=prod
>         -ou=hostdefinitions
> ```

Users:

```
cn=user2
gidNumber=235
homeDirectory=/home/user2
uid=user2
uidNumber=235
userPassword={SSHA hashed password}
cn=user1,ou=People,dc=myorg,dc=com
objectClass=account,extensibleObject,posixAccount,shadowAccount,top

cn=user1
gidNumber=234
homeDirectory=/home/user1
uid=user1
uidNumber=234
userPassword={SSHA hashed password}
cn=user1,ou=People,dc=myorg,dc=com
objectClass=account,extensibleObject,posixAccount,shadowAccount,top
```

ACLs:

```
access to dn.subtree="ou=nonprod,dc=myorg,dc=com"
    by dn.exact="cn=user1,ou=People,dc=myorg,dc=com" manage
    by dn.exact="cn=user2,ou=People,dc=myorg,dc=com" none

 access to dn.subtree="ou=prod,dc=myorg,dc=com"
    by dn.exact="cn=user1,ou=People,dc=myorg,dc=com" none
    by dn.exact="cn=user2,ou=People,dc=myorg,dc=com" manage

 access to dn.base="" by * read
 access to dn.base="cn=subschema" by * read

 access to *
    by self write
    by anonymous auth
```

Comment: That's not what I want, you still have to add lines for each new user. But I think what I want is impossible...